# Javascript in VueJs: how to return data object from async fetch instead of Promise

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, promise, fetch

I have this action in store

```
actions: {
    testLogin(context, credentials) {
        const loginService = new FetchClient();
        let d = loginService.post('login', credentials);
        console.log(d);
    },
```

and this function in another class imported to store

```
async post(endpoint, params) {
    await fetch(this.url + endpoint, {
        'method': 'POST',
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then( (data) => {
            this.returnData =  data.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    return this.returnData;
}
```

And I get `Promise {<pending>}` which I can extract data from inside the fetch class but can't access data if I'm in the store because it's a Promise not an object. How can I solve this?

Comment: As `async` methods return promises you need to work with that.

Comment: Simply put, an asynchronous result can't be made synchronous without a psychic or time travel - javascript contains neither

Answer (score 1):

Put the return statement inside the second `then` block:

```
async post(endpoint, params) {
    await fetch(this.url + endpoint, {
        'method': 'POST',
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then( (data) => {
            this.returnData =  data.data;
            return this.returnData;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I would even recommend you use the following code for better legibility:

```
async post(endpoint, params) {
    const response = await fetch(this.url + endpoint, {
        'method': 'POST',
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
        const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
        throw new Error(message);
    }
    
    const resp_data = await response.json()

    return resp_data.data
}
```

Then call your method like so:

```
post(endpoint, params)
    .then(data => {// do something with data})
    .catch(error => {
        error.message; // 'An error has occurred: 404'
    });
```

refer to [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/) async/await guide

Comment: Can recommend to always add a try/catch block in order to handle errors better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
async testLogin(context, credentials) {
    const loginService = new FetchClient();
    let d = await loginService.post('login', credentials);
    console.log(d);
}
```

Comment: It does log the data but in the js file I use it I find it returned as promise not as data

Answer (score 0):

```
As @Ayudh mentioned, try the following code:

    async post(endpoint, params) {
    try{
        let response = await fetch(this.url + endpoint, {
            'method': 'POST',
            headers: this.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(params),
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        this.returnData =  data.data;
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    
    return this.returnData;
}
```